# How to extract matrix values by subscripts in a list being a list in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a question regarding matrix value extractions in R. 
Specifically,I have a list storing the subscripts and a corresponding matrix. What I want to do is to extract matrix values according to the subscripts of the list, but still being a list.

For example：

The subscripts list A: ((1,2,3),(4,5),(6,7,8,9))
The matrix B: [3,4,12,35,35,13,2,3,34]

The expected result list C: ((3,4,12),(35,35),(13,2,3,34))

I tried use "[]" or "[[]]" matrix manipulation, but not working. 
How can I do this calculation?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read guidelines how to ask questions on SO

Answer (score 1):

```
subs <- list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5),c(6,7,8,9))
mat <- as.matrix(c(3,4,12,35,35,13,2,3,34))

lapply(subs, function(s) { mat[s] })
# [[1]]
# [1]  3  4 12
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 35 35
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 13  2  3 34
```